# Integrating $ \frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2(x)|\cos(x)| |\sin(x)| dx }{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2(x)|\cos(x)| dx } $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, area

I'm trying to integrate $ \frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2(x)|\cos(x)| |\sin(x)| dx  }{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2(x)|\cos(x)| dx } $

I understand that $|\cos(x)|$ and $|\sin(x)|$ when integrated over $- \pi$ and $ \pi$ is the same as integrating over $0$ and $ \pi/2$ and multiplying by 4. However the next line in the solutions is $ \frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^3(x)\sin(x) dx  }{\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^3(x) dx } $

I'm not sure how we get this, would appreciate any help

Comment: on $(0,\pi/2)$ $\cos$ and $\sin$ are both positive

Comment: $$
\int_0^{{\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}}} {\cos ^3 x\sin xdx}  = \int_0^{{\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}}} {\frac{{\left( {1 + \cos 2x} \right)}}{2}\cos x\sin xdx}  = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{{\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}}} {\left( {1 + \cos 2x} \right)\sin 2xdx} 
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both integrals you can use substitution.

For the top:

Let $u=\cos x$, so $du=-\sin x dx$.

When $x=0$ then $u=1$.

When $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $u=0$.

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos^3x \sin x dx=-\int_1^0 u^3 du=-\frac14u^4\bigg|_1^0=\frac14$$

$$\int_0

For the bottom:

Let $u=\sin x$ so $du=\cos x dx$

When $x=0$ then $u=0$.

When $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $u=1$.

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^3x dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\sin^2x)\cos x dx=\int_0^11-u^2 du=u-\frac{u^3}{3}\bigg|_0^1=\frac23$$

So the fraction is:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{3}{8}$$